# Implementing A Website like Google Waypoints

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

Actually I am new in web development and doing work by search and reading tutorials. I am confused by google API and need some help.

I am using nodejs and need to show the google map in my view and show path of a vehicle on map. I have read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints#try-it-yourself and found the waypoints in direction is my solution.

According to the steps at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#key
I have created a project, added libraries and also get api key from google.then to test my api key I made a html page just like a page which is defined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints#try-it-yourself) 
And I got an error after loading map.It

> Oops! Something went wrong.
>
> This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript
>   console for technical details.

And consol log said the url is not authorised so I added url to Domain Verification section at Credential of this [link](https://developers.google.com/console.)
but the error still appears.

I am sure there is a lot of info which I did not understand them but I need to know What's wrong on my work? Do I skip any step?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to fix my problem! I did not enable javascript API and that caused error.

To enable JavaScript Api do this

Go to API Manager
Click on Dashboard
Click on Enable API with Plus button
Search for Google Maps JavaScript API and Click on that
You will find Enable button there. Click to enable API.